# Searching the tags of all Stack Exchange sites before asking a question, to find out where the question belongs

Tags: support, tags, search

Let's imagine I want to ask a question about "big data" and I am not familiar with Stack Exchange.

Normally I should guess which stack is the right stack to ask my question, but is there any way to search for a tag anywhere in the Stack Exchange network, and then find out which site is the right one?

Comment: Salt exists as a tag on both SO and Cooking; it's not so much existence of a tag that matters, but the context you're using it in.  What expertise do you need to answer your question?

Comment: I think there is a connection between the context of a question and the tag.

Comment: In some cases, sure.  But the existence of a tag does not guarantee a question is on-topic on the site.  Focus on the problem space itself, not a specific tag.

Comment: Ok, good point, then how to find the right Stack to ask a question the would be on-topic?

Comment: @fbueckert But it sure helps filter the potential set of sites to choose from, making it easier to make a final decision.

Comment: You can ask here where the right place to ask your question would be. Make sure to use [tag:site-recommendation].

Comment: There's a network-wide tag search using the "filter questions" tab on Stackexchange.com - https://stackexchange.com/filters/369971/my-filter

Comment: @Sonic Eh. I think that's relying a little too much on a tag's existence. A tag may not exist on the target site, which leads to a false result. Better to focus on the area of expertise.

Comment: What I mean is with the help of searching tags one way to ask a question on-topic in right Stack and it is a suggestion but your way is the complete another way.

Comment: The existence of a tag doesn't guarantee your question will be on-topic.  It means others have asked about that topic space before, but doesn't automatically mean your question will be accepted.  If you have a specific question you want to ask, you can ask it here, with [tag:site-recommendation], and people can tell you where the best place to ask it would be.

Comment: @fbueckert it is like asking a question two time, I want to keep it more simple/

Comment: That's your best bet, if you don't know where to ask it; we can help you with where to ask, if the question is acceptable somewhere in the network.  The other way is to narrow down where you think the problem is, and figure out which site has the expertise to deal with it.  First one is probably faster.

Comment: @fbueckert I partially agree with you but "it the best bet" yet. maybe with developing the new posssibilty, I should help in a better way, let me make an example: if someone has a question about "RSA encryption protocol" it is related to network, security, and cryptography SE but if the person knows the "side-channel-attack"  it would be definitely cryptography SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags) is a SEDE query you could use. Note that due to the variable nature of how tags are created, you'd need to search for both [`bigdata`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags?query=bigdata):

[image]

and [`big-data`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags?query=big-data):

[image]

As stressed by the comments, a tag being often used (even in the same context, like choosing Cooking's 'salt' when you have a question about flavour, instead of the more often used Stack Overflow's 'salt') does not mean your question is on-topic; please read the [Tour](/tour) and the [Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?"](/help/on-topic) on the *target* site to make sure your question is well-received.

Comment: [This link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags) is the answer I was looking for, you did a good job by the development of "the query"!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to experiment with the query; if you're new to SQL or the Data Explorer in general, you can take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Comment: The SEDE query link does not work anymore!

Comment: *Which* link (I posted three of them) and FWIW, they do work for me. I just have to click the 'Run Query' button at the button, which is normal.

Comment: When I click on the link it does not work and shows the following error, please look at the link [SEDE](http://s2.picofile.com/file/8369630126/Meta_SE.jpg)

Comment: OK, that's the first link, but it's **really** weird that it's not working for you. Can you access the SEDE homepage: https://data.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: No, I face the same Error !!!

Comment: Maybe it's your location... probably worth opening a new question about this.

Comment: i did ask a new question in following the link [Facing Error to access “SEDE”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332221/facing-error-to-access-sede)