# Search tags across sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

I'm looking to subscribe to a few tags I'm interested in, but I don't know which sites in the network may use them.

I can go to http://stackexchange.com and use the *Favourite tags* filter, and see my tags across all sites.

[image: Favourite Tags view]

I can also add a custom filter which will indeed allow me to select tags across sites but without telling me which sites they belong to.

[image: Custom filter view]

Wouldn't it be nice, a searchable "tags" view in the main StackExchange site?

Comment: Strongly related, possible dupe: [Searching the tags of all Stack Exchange sites before asking a question, to find out where the question belongs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329223/398063) - Glorfindel's answer provides a way to search tags network-wide via SEDE

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for the finding! as my post is specifically requesting the feature, and as I don't think using SEDE is user-friendly enough to browse tags.. I think I'll keep this post open :-).

Comment: It's possible to search for *questions* in a specific tag on the whole network - for example, here is [the tag (google)](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle%5D), But if I understand correctely, hits is not what you want - you want to search among tags. (Although if that feature does not exist, this might be useful, too.)