# How do I list the SE sites that have a specified tag, sorted by the number of questions with that tag?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I whipped up a [Chinese.SE meta post](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/alternative-sites-for-not-really-about-the-chinese-language-questions) in which:

> ## Sites that have a [China] tag...
>
> - [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 718 Q's)
> - [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 281 Q's)
> - [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 201 Q's)
> - [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 74 Q's)
> - [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 54 Q's)
>
> [snip]
>
> - [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 6 Q's)
> - [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 6 Q's)
> - [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 5 Q's)
> - [Genealogy and Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 4 Q's)
> - [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) ([tag](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china); 1 Q')

I did this somewhat manually (using `grep` and `sort -u` on [this search](https://stackexchange.com/search?page=1&q=%5Bchina%5D%20is%3Aquestion&pagesize=2000)), which took a while (and may have some bugs).  I feel like there is a better way via [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to create this list.  I would also be interested in replacing "China" with other keywords.

**Question**: How do I list the SE sites that have a specified tag, sorted by the number of questions with that tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I have written [such a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags) 6-8 months ago, to answer the question [Searching the tags of all Stack Exchange sites before asking a question, to find out where the question belongs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329223/295232).

[image]

It actually searches for tags *containing* a certain query; feel free to fork it to make one which looks for exact matches.

Comment: Actually, it's better left alone---I found more results.  Thanks!