# Which SE sites accept "identification" questions?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, scope

Various sites on the Stack Exchange network take questions of the form "please identify this thing", perhaps from a photo or a description (where the nature of the "thing" would depend on the individual site in question). Some site scopes place strong restrictions on such questions or disallow them altogether. I've seen and participated in debates on various site metas, where some people claim that "many" or "most" sites disallow them while others claim that "many" or "most" sites allow them. Let's collate the facts and find out for sure.

**Which SE sites accept identification questions?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Partial answer - community wiki, feel free to edit**

The following sites accept identification questions (the link in each case goes to a list of all questions in the relevant tag or tags)

- [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/*-identification)
- [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tags/*-identification)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-object)
- [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Beer, Wine & Spirits](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification)
- [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-bike)
- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game)
- [Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification)
- [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this)
- [Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this)
- [Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this)
- [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-identification)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-identification)
- [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification)
- [Genealogy & Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-identification)
- [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-identification)
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)
- [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification)
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unidentifiable)
- [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)
- [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/*-identification)
- [Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification)
- [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-*)
- [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-identification)
- [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/*-identification/)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-identification)
- [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this)

Comment: You can use a SEDE query to search for tag names containing [identify](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags?query=identify) and [identification](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062082/search-the-stack-exchange-network-for-tags?query=identification). (That doesn't mean it's on-topic, see e.g. [this tag wiki](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-movie/info).)

Comment: @Glorfindel good ideas never come alone  ... https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1341509

Comment: @rene in my case, it was a [repost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329236/295232) ...

Comment: Ah, well ... never too late for me to have a go at it ...

Comment: I adapted @rene's query, and got till chess with updating the list. Query is [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1341582)

Comment: Why some with *-identification and some with one single tag? (e.g. SF&F)

Comment: In case there are multiple tags that deal with Identification @Shadow10YearsWizard

Comment: Shameless plug for SE filtered questions for the known identification tags (with some false positives): [ID Galore](https://stackexchange.com/filters/344129/id-galore)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. false positives are due to synonymisations, but I guess you already figured that out yourself ;)